# how to run this on MySQL Query

Tags: mysql

i wan't to change this.

from

```
equip mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
```

to

```
equip int(11) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
```

from

```
slotchange SMALLINT(3) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
```

to

```
moves int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
```

from

```
char_opt INT( 11 ) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
```

to

```
unban_time int(11) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
```

from

```
type enum('M','P','L','T','V','S','N','C','A','R','G','E','B','O','I','X','D','U') NOT NULL default 'P',
```

to

```
type enum('M','P','L','T','V','S','N','C','A','R','G','E','B','O','I','X','D','U','$') NOT NULL default 'P',
```

Comment: have you tried `ALTER` function?

Comment: I meant `ALTER` statement. :D

Answer (score 2):

Here's the queries :
equip column :

```
ALTER TABLE your_table MODIFY COLUMN equip int(11) unsigned NOT NULL default '0'
```

slotchange to moves :

```
ALTER TABLE your_table CHANGE slotchange moves int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
```

char_opt to unban_time :

```
ALTER TABLE your_table CHANGE char_opt unban_time int(11) unsigned NOT NULL default '0'
```

type column :

```
ALTER TABLE your_table MODIFY COLUMN type enum('M','P','L','T','V','S','N','C','A','R','G','E','B','O','I','X','D','U','$') NOT NULL default 'P'
```

`MODIFY` is used to change the data type and other properties of your column and `CHANGE` is used to change the name and other properties of your table column.
Oh, and run the queries one-by-one :D